# In WebGL, can I use a matrix to draw an object offset in screen space?

Tags: matrix, 3d, webgl

I have a simple object that draws a 3d gizmo at 0, 0, 0. If the camera is centered on 0, 0, 0, then it draws the gizmo at the center of the screen.

[image]

I would like to "lift" this gizmo and render it at the bottom right of the screen in screen coordinates, without rotating it. Basically, I want the gizmo to show the rotation of the center of the screen without blocking the view and without having to focus on a specific point. So I want to do away with the model matrix, or something.

I got the following to work by translating the projection matrix:

[image]

```
this.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.modelMatrixUniform, false, modelMatrix);
this.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.viewMatrixUniform, false, viewMatrix);

const bottomRightMat = mat4.create();
mat4.translate(bottomRightMat, projectionMatrix, [5, -3, 0]);
this.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this.projectionMatrixUniform, false, bottomRightMat);
this.gl.drawElements(this.gl.LINES, this.indexBuffer.getLength(), this.gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

But the gizmo has been rotated into its new position. The red line should still point down and to the left, since that's the direction of the positive X axis at the center of the screen. Also, the numbers 5 and 3 are arbitrary, and I don't think they would work at different zooms or camera locations.

Is there a way to specify a matrix transform that takes the center of the screen and translates it in screen space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to change the viewport when rendering that object.

```
// size of area in bottom right
const miniWidth = 150;
const miniHeight = 100;
gl.viewport(gl.canvas.width - miniWidth, gl.canvas.height - miniHeight, miniWidth, miniHeight);

// now draw. you'll need to zoom in, like set the camera closer
// or move the object closer or add a scale matrix after the projection
// matrix as in projection * scale * view * ...
```

you'll need a projection matrix that matches the aspect ratio of the new viewport and you'll either need to scale the object, put the camera closer, or add a 2D scale between the projection and view matrices.
Remember to put the viewport back to the full canvas to render the rest of the scene.

```js
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
void main() {
  gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * position;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0), 1);
}
`

const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  position: [
    -1, -1, -1,
     1, -1, -1,
     1,  1, -1,
    -1,  1, -1,
    -1, -1,  1,
     1, -1,  1,
     1,  1,  1,
    -1,  1,  1,
  ],
  indices: {
    numComponents: 2,
    data: [
      0, 1,
      1, 2,
      2, 3,
      3, 0,
      4, 5,
      5, 6,
      6, 7,
      7, 4,
      0, 4,
      1, 5,
      2, 6,
      3, 7,
    ],
  },
});

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  const fov = 90 * Math.PI / 180;
  const zNear = 0.5;
  const zFar = 100;
  const projection = mat4.perspective(mat4.create(),
      fov, gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, zNear, zFar);
  const eye = [0, 0, 10];
  const target = [0, 0, 0];
  const up = [0, 1, 0];
  const view = mat4.lookAt(mat4.create(), eye, target, up);

  drawCube([-8, 0, 0], projection, view);
  drawCube([-4, 0, 0], projection, view);
  drawCube([ 0, 0, 0], projection, view);
  drawCube([ 4, 0, 0], projection, view);
  drawCube([ 8, 0, 0], projection, view);

  const iconAreaWidth  = 100;
  const iconAreaHeight = 75;
  gl.viewport(
      gl.canvas.width - iconAreaWidth, 0, 
      iconAreaWidth, iconAreaHeight);     
  const iconProjection = mat4.perspective(mat4.create(),
      fov, iconAreaWidth / iconAreaHeight, zNear, zFar);
  // compute the zoom size need to make things the sngs
  const scale = gl.canvas.clientHeight / iconAreaHeight;
  mat4.scale(iconProjection, iconProjection, [scale, scale, 1]);
  drawCube([ 0, 0, 0], iconProjection, view);

  function drawCube(translation, projection, view) {
    const viewProjection = mat4.multiply(mat4.create(), projection, view);
    const world = mat4.multiply(
       mat4.create(),
       mat4.fromTranslation(mat4.create(), translation),
       mat4.fromRotation(mat4.create(), time, [0.42, 0.56, 0.70]));
    const worldViewProjection = mat4.multiply(mat4.create(), viewProjection, world);

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      u_worldViewProjection: worldViewProjection,
    });
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo, gl.LINES);
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; background: #CDE; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix.js"></script>
```

Another is to compute an off center frustum projection matrix. Instead of `mat4.perspective` use `mat4.frustum`

```
function perspectiveWithCenter(
    fieldOfView, width, height, near, far, centerX = 0, centerY = 0) {
  const aspect = width / height;

  // compute the top and bottom of the near plane of the view frustum
  const top = Math.tan(fieldOfView * 0.5) * near;
  const bottom = -top;

  // compute the left and right of the near plane of the view frustum
  const left = aspect * bottom;
  const right = aspect * top;

  // compute width and height of the near plane of the view frustum
  const nearWidth = right - left;
  const nearHeight = top - bottom;

  // convert the offset from canvas units to near plane units
  const offX = centerX * nearWidth / width;
  const offY = centerY * nearHeight / height;

  const m = mat4.create();
  mat4.frustum(
        m,
        left + offX,
        right + offX,
        bottom + offY,
        top + offY,
        near,
        far);
  return m;
}
```

So to draw your gizmo set call something like

```
  const gizmoCenterX = -gl.canvas.clientWidth  / 2 + 50;
  const gizmoCenterY =  gl.canvas.clientHeight / 2 - 50;
  const offsetProjection = perspectiveWithCenter(
      fov, gl.canvas.clientWidth, gl.canvas.clientHeight, zNear, zFar,
      gizmoCenterX, gizmoCenterY);
```

```js
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
void main() {
  gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * position;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0), 1);
}
`

const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  position: [
    -1, -1, -1,
     1, -1, -1,
     1,  1, -1,
    -1,  1, -1,
    -1, -1,  1,
     1, -1,  1,
     1,  1,  1,
    -1,  1,  1,
  ],
  indices: {
    numComponents: 2,
    data: [
      0, 1,
      1, 2,
      2, 3,
      3, 0,
      4, 5,
      5, 6,
      6, 7,
      7, 4,
      0, 4,
      1, 5,
      2, 6,
      3, 7,
    ],
  },
});

function perspectiveWithCenter(
    fieldOfView, width, height, near, far, centerX = 0, centerY = 0) {
  const aspect = width / height;

  // compute the top and bottom of the near plane of the view frustum
  const top = Math.tan(fieldOfView * 0.5) * near;
  const bottom = -top;

  // compute the left and right of the near plane of the view frustum
  const left = aspect * bottom;
  const right = aspect * top;

  // compute width and height of the near plane of the view frustum
  const nearWidth = right - left;
  const nearHeight = top - bottom;

  // convert the offset from canvas units to near plane units
  const offX = centerX * nearWidth / width;
  const offY = centerY * nearHeight / height;

  const m = mat4.create();
  mat4.frustum(
        m,
        left + offX,
        right + offX,
        bottom + offY,
        top + offY,
        near,
        far);
  return m;
}

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  const fov = 90 * Math.PI / 180;
  const zNear = 0.5;
  const zFar = 100;
  const projection = perspectiveWithCenter(
      fov, gl.canvas.clientWidth, gl.canvas.clientHeight, zNear, zFar);
  const eye = [0, 0, 10];
  const target = [0, 0, 0];
  const up = [0, 1, 0];
  const view = mat4.lookAt(mat4.create(), eye, target, up);

  drawCube([-8, 0, 0], projection, view);
  drawCube([-4, 0, 0], projection, view);
  drawCube([ 0, 0, 0], projection, view);
  drawCube([ 4, 0, 0], projection, view);
  drawCube([ 8, 0, 0], projection, view);

  const gizmoCenterX = -gl.canvas.clientWidth  / 2 + 50;
  const gizmoCenterY =  gl.canvas.clientHeight / 2 - 50;
  const offsetProjection = perspectiveWithCenter(
      fov, gl.canvas.clientWidth, gl.canvas.clientHeight, zNear, zFar,
      gizmoCenterX, gizmoCenterY);
  drawCube([ 0, 0, 0], offsetProjection, view);

  function drawCube(translation, projection, view) {
    const viewProjection = mat4.multiply(mat4.create(), projection, view);
    const world = mat4.multiply(
       mat4.create(),
       mat4.fromTranslation(mat4.create(), translation),
       mat4.fromRotation(mat4.create(), time, [0.42, 0.56, 0.70]));
    const worldViewProjection = mat4.multiply(mat4.create(), viewProjection, world);

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      u_worldViewProjection: worldViewProjection,
    });
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo, gl.LINES);
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; background: #CDE; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix.js"></script>
```

Comment: I went with the modified viewport. Though I needed a closer camera/view matrix and a new perspective matrix with a square aspect, it is a very simple solution! Here's the result: https://imgur.com/a/2Pxt9ar

Thanks.